# How to vertically align spans with text and image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have now been looking for hours (obviously not in the right place!)

Please consider this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/DYLs4/9/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span id="text24">Text 24</span>
    <span id="text12">Text 12</span>
    <span id="icon"></span>
</div>
```

css:

```
#text24{
    font-size:24px; color:#999;   
}
#text12{
    font-size:12px; color:#000;  
}
#icon{
    height:36px; width:36px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(some-icon.png);
}​
```

​
[image: Result]

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

- Center vertically the text24 (relative to the image)
- Align the bottom of text12 with bottom of text24
- Make sure the whole thing work in IE6 -> chrome

[image: Goal]

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: did you try <img> and set vertical-align:middle;  ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to your image.

**EDIT**

Per comments, this solution also requires **display:inline-block;**.

Comment: Almost! With vertical-align:middle, text24 is aligned with the top, not the middle of the image

Comment: Wrap the two text spans around with another span and use `vertical-align: middle` on this and on `#icon`

Comment: @slash197: It worked with this new wrapper with `vertical-align: middle` and also `display:inline-block;` Pure genius! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is working

http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/frsA5/1/

Answer (score 0):

I know most of designers hate use table for layout, but let me try anyway.
You can use `valign` of table.

Comment: This has been on mind as well but with a table I will loose the flexibility in the future to reskin the page and -say- put text12 below text24...

Answer (score 0):

Final result

http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/frsA5/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span id="text24">Text 24</span>
    <span id="text12">Text 12</span>
    <img src="http://www.adlittle.com/fileadmin/templates/images/rss_feed_icon.png" id="icon"/>
</div>

#wrapper{
    position:absolute; left:0;
}
#text24{
    font-size:24px; color:#999; font-weight:bold;
}
#text12{
    font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:bold; }
#icon{
    height:36px; width:36px;
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but text24 is aligned with the top, not the middle of the image. Looks like Slash197 came up with a good solution. Sorry!