# Vertically aligning span with text, select, and span with image on single line?

Tags: html, css

I've seen similar questions like [How to vertically align spans with text and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615365/how-to-vertically-align-spans-with-text-and-image), but for the life of me, I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my minimal example as a whole html page:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 16px serif;
}
#mydiv span {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#mydiv select {
    font: 16px serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <div id="mydiv">
    <span>Testing 1:</span>
    <select id="myselect"><option value="1">[My option]</option></select>
    <span><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASCAYAAABWzo5XAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAQxJREFUOI2l1DtOA0EMBuBPiGMgUBo4AQWioEAkCCpuACUSuQLcgYI+4QJ0NAREkWOkiBBCPBraFLsU6w3L7uZFfsmSx2P/Y8/YQz1a6GKAUcggbAc1/pdlwxb6SGfIEzYi5gpJkWQP3+GYoIc2miFtPMdeinfcFNbjTHKSYZBOwhE+arKkUM4Qa1NIclzXEbUK5UzLJEd+JxWibii9JUjSVeyG090MkjOcysqvxShYm3NkNBErywSXiV5C31yWqB/6yT/iO7IuP2fx589xHDEJdnLjog3ZwFvE3Bc3FhmRfbyG7yfWyw7loX3Ahb9D++i3Ib+wPem0eb6RRHbBjSlZj3GIW9WPrROlVfADiJ5vX7sneXIAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/></span>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would want, the span with text, the select next to it, and the span with image to be vertically aligned - middle or bottom. However, what I get is in Firefox 43 is this:

[image: ff-clean]

Somehow, the span/text, the select and the span/image do not look vertically aligned to me; so to check, here is a montage from Firefox:

[image: ff-merged]

So, how can I get these elements aligned vertically on a single line - either middle or bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came as close as I could:

[image: ff-clear]

Basically:

- The baseline of the texts in first `span` and `select` are (nearly) aligned
- The image `span` is centered vertically in respect to the `select`

... and this is as good as I'd have it, I guess. Somewhat strangely, there's no `vertical-align: middle;` anywhere in the CSS to get this output? Here is an overlay from the visual inspect in Firefox:

[image: ff-merged.png]

... and here is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 16px serif;
}
#mydiv span#s1 {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    display: inline-block;
}
#mydiv span#s2 {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    display: inline-block;
}
#mydiv span img {
    vertical-align: sub;
  line-height: 1em;
}
#mydiv select {
    font: 16px serif;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <div id="mydiv">
    <span id="s1">Testing 1:</span>
    <select id="myselect"><option value="1">[My option]</option></select>
    <span id="s2"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASCAYAAABWzo5XAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAQxJREFUOI2l1DtOA0EMBuBPiGMgUBo4AQWioEAkCCpuACUSuQLcgYI+4QJ0NAREkWOkiBBCPBraFLsU6w3L7uZFfsmSx2P/Y8/YQz1a6GKAUcggbAc1/pdlwxb6SGfIEzYi5gpJkWQP3+GYoIc2miFtPMdeinfcFNbjTHKSYZBOwhE+arKkUM4Qa1NIclzXEbUK5UzLJEd+JxWibii9JUjSVeyG090MkjOcysqvxShYm3NkNBErywSXiV5C31yWqB/6yT/iO7IuP2fx589xHDEJdnLjog3ZwFvE3Bc3FhmRfbyG7yfWyw7loX3Ahb9D++i3Ib+wPem0eb6RRHbBjSlZj3GIW9WPrROlVfADiJ5vX7sneXIAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/></span>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If a better answer than this appears, I'll re-accept it ...

Answer (score 3):

Try this maybe:

```
#mydiv span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the Dropdown a `margin-bottom: -3px;` to align the texts. 
Remove the `vertical-align` from the image-span, and give the image the same `margin-bottom: -3px;`.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, but I'd like to avoid manually adjusting margins, cheers!